# Need Help Installing Steam With Wine (Bug)

Tags: wine, steam, winetricks

When I try to install `steam` with `wine` and `winetricks`, its only says :

```
Checksum for /home/viktor/.cache/winetricks/steam/SteamInstall.msi did not match, retrying download
```

And :

```
sha1sum mismatch! Rename /home/viktor/.cache/winetricks/steam/SteamInstall.msi and try again.
```

And then it just closes down.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Try download [SteamInstall.msi](http://storefront.steampowered.com/download/SteamInstall.msi) from Steam website.

Then run it (as Install Windows Software) on wineskin wrapper

Comment: thanks for your anwanser i have the steaminstall.msi downloaded how do i do next step?

Comment: i tried isntall it by starting the steaminstall.msi with wine everything goes good but when i try to login it crashes

Comment: its working now i just updated wine verison

Comment: If it's working, could you mark my answer as correct? You need to click the V underneath the upvote/downvote arrows